# Android sharing image doesn't work

Tags: android, android-intent, android-sdcard, android-sharing

I am trying to share a screenshot of the application using the following code:

```
View content = findViewById(R.id.layoutHome);
content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bitmap = content.getDrawingCache();

File sdCardDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File image = new File(sdCardDirectory,"temp.png");

// Encode the file as a PNG image.
FileOutputStream outStream;
try {
  outStream = new FileOutputStream(image);
  bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
  outStream.flush();
  outStream.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}

String url = "file://" + sdCardDirectory.toString() + "Images/temp.png";

Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("image/*");
String shareBody = "Here is the share content body";
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Subject Here");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, url);
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,shareBody);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
```

Logcat:

```
10-10 14:20:16.631: W/Bundle(16349): Key android.intent.extra.STREAM expected Parcelable but value was a java.lang.String.  The default value <null> was returned.
10-10 14:20:16.658: W/Bundle(16349): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
10-10 14:20:16.658: W/Bundle(16349): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to android.os.Parcelable
10-10 14:20:16.658: W/Bundle(16349):    at android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(Bundle.java:1171)
10-10 14:20:16.658: W/Bundle(16349):    at android.content.Intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.java:4140)
10-10 14:20:16.658: W/Bundle(16349):    at android.content.Intent.migrateExtraStreamToClipData(Intent.java:6665)
10-10 14:20:16.658: W/Bundle(16349):    at android.content.Intent.migrateExtraStreamToClipData(Intent.java:6650)
10-10 14:20:16.658: W/Bundle(16349):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1410)
10-10 14:20:16.658: W/Bundle(16349):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
10-10 14:20:16.658: W/Bundle(16349):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3312)
10-10 14:20:16.658: W/Bundle(16349):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3522)
10-10 14:20:16.658: W/Bundle(16349):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3490)
10-10 14:20:16.658: W/Bundle(16349):    at com.example.simplegraph.EconActivity$DrawerItemClickListener.onItemClick(EconActivity.java:182)
10-10 14:20:16.658: W/Bundle(16349):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
10-10 14:20:16.658: W/Bundle(16349):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1086)
10-10 14:20:16.658: W/Bundle(16349):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2855)
10-10 14:20:16.658: W/Bundle(16349):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3529)
10-10 14:20:16.658: W/Bundle(16349):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
10-10 14:20:16.658: W/Bundle(16349):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-10 14:20:16.658: W/Bundle(16349):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-10 14:20:16.658: W/Bundle(16349):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
10-10 14:20:16.658: W/Bundle(16349):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-10 14:20:16.658: W/Bundle(16349):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-10 14:20:16.658: W/Bundle(16349):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
10-10 14:20:16.658: W/Bundle(16349):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-10 14:20:16.658: W/Bundle(16349):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**The problem:**
When I try to share with gmail, gmail is force closed. When I try to share with Facebook, Facebook silently rejects the post. Messaging brings up the messenger, but is empty. Sharing works without adding in the image.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First, never use concatenation to build file paths, let alone `Uri` values.

Second, `EXTRA_STREAM` is supposed to hold a `Uri`, not a `String`.

Third, since you know the right MIME type (`image/png`), use it, instead of a wildcard.

Fourth, never build the same path twice. Here you create `File image` the right way, then ignore that value.

So, dump the `String url` line, replace `image/*` with `image/png`, and modify:

```
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, url);
```

to be:

```
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I was combining multiple solutions from stackoverflow to get my own solution. Thanks for the input, it now works.

Comment: Uri.fromFile(file) let me go home on time!  Thanks!

Comment: this is my image link http://tree.solucionatime.com/uploads/024c546c9ca7bd8dc7bb0651dbf726a7.jpg  i want to share image on instagram

Answer (score 1):

Also, consider using the android.support.v4.content.FileProvider class to share your file using a content URI instead of a file URI. It's more secure. See the [reference documentation for FileProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass Content URI all the time (at least in Android 5.1+). here's how to get a content path from a Bitmap :

```
Bitmap bitmap;//this should be your bitmap
String MediaFilePath = Images.Media.insertImage(MainActivity.getContentResolver(), bitmap, FileName, null);
```

And then to share :

```
public static void ShareFile(String ContentPath, String Mime)
    {
        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

        sharingIntent.setType(Mime);

        Uri FileUri = Uri.parse( ContentPath );


        sharingIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        sharingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, FileUri);

        MainActivity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share to..."));
    }
```